# What would be the best approach to use CompletableFuture while running a stream of asynchronous tasks?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, concurrency, completable-future

I have a spring component EventSvcFacade which HAS-A list of three EventValidationSvc implementation class instances. Each of these classes implements the method `boolean validate(T request)`, takes the same input but calls different APIs on the input, processes the result, and returns a boolean. This flow is thus designed for concurrent invocation. I have figured out two approaches to return a list of Boolean from the stream of tasks. Can anyone suggest, on what factors one approach is better than the other, or is there any other better approach?

```
@Component
public class EventSvcFacade {

    @Autowired
    private List<EventValidationSvc<EventRequest>> validationSvcs;

    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor;

    public List<Boolean> firstApproach(){
      final List<CompletableFuture<Boolean>> futures = validationSvcs.stream().map(service -> 
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service.validate(eventRequest), threadPoolExecutor))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());                                                                                      
      final List<Boolean> values = futures.stream().map(CompletableFuture :: 
            join).collect(Collectors.toList());
      return values;
    }

    public List<Boolean> secondApproach() {
      final List<Boolean> values = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
      final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(validationSvcs.size());
      validationSvcs.stream().forEach(service -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {         
            try{
             values.add(service.validate(eventRequest));
            }finally{
             countDownLatch.countDown();
            }
          }, threadPoolExecutor)
      );
      countDownLatch.await();
      return values;
   }
}
```

Comment: Your second approach does not maintain the order. Further, it has no feedback on failures. It will just hang.

Comment: Thanks! So other than calling join() or get() there is no way to notify the main thread about the exception from the task running inside CompletableFuture.

Comment: When you chain an action with `whenComplete` or a function via `handle`, it will also be evaluated in the exceptional case, getting the exception as parameter, which allows to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is cleaner as it is [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function): since it does not rely on side effects it is easier to reason about and less likely to break when code is modified later.

Also the first approach does not rely on ad-hoc synchronisation constructs such like the second approach does with the `CountDownLatch` instance. Should your preconditions change and there only be two services to call, the first approach will continue to work while the second one would never return.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on the preconditions change, since what you mentioned can be fixed by instantiating the `CountDownLatch` as
`final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(validationSvcs.size());`
and enclosing the method inside an `If` clause

Comment: Yes you could do that. Still this is external coordination that is potentially error prone while the inherent mechanisms of the `CompletableFuture` already provide you with all you need.